# Counter increase in child & parent with fork()

Tags: c, linux, fork

I've a problem with this little program:

```
    int main() {

  pid_t process;
  int count= 0;

  switch(process= fork()) {

    case -1:
      printf("Fork error!\n\n");
      exit(1);
    break;

    case 0: //child
      printf("Process CHILD: PID= %d, Value= %d \n", getpid(), process);
      printf("Coounter NOT increased: %d\n", count);
      printf("Increase counter...\n");
      sleep(2);
      count= count + 2;
      printf("Counter increased: %d\n\n", count);
      exit(0);
    break;

    default: //parent
      wait(0);
      printf("Process PARENT: PID= %d, Value= %d\n", getpid(), process);
      printf("Counter value: %d\n\n", count);
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I increase the counter in the child but in the parent the counter not increase... why?

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because after `fork`, parent process and child process are different processes, and they each have their own copy of the variable `count`.

Answer (score 5):

Because parent and child are not running in the same process.

The memory used for the variable is *different* in each process. This is the point of processes, by the way.

Look into "[shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)" if you really want to do this with processes, or threads if you just want multi-processing in a single process' memory.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you fork, the process image is copied.  Unlike with threads, one process modifying global variables will not affect the other.  That's actually one of the benefits of using multiple processes in many cases.  In fact, copy-on-write can be used to eliminate actual copying, but when you increment the counter in the child, a copy must be made so the parent doesn't see it.

Answer (score 3):

When you do the fork it will create a new child process. New Child process has it's own memory, stack, local/global variable space.

Both process starts execution from the same point where fork is callled, but with different memory space. So One process's memory changes will not reflect in other process.

YOu can use shared memory in case if you want to use the same memory between two process.

Another approach is you can redirect the variable value from child process to standard out stream and read it from the parent process.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count= 0;

int main() {

  pid_t process;


  switch(process= fork()) {

    case -1:
      printf("Fork error!\n\n");
      exit(1);
    break;

    case 0: //child
      printf("Process CHILD: PID= %d, Value= %d \n", getpid(), process);
      printf("Coounter NOT increased: %d\n", count);
      printf("Increase counter...\n");
      sleep(2);
      count= count + 2;
      printf("Counter increased: %d\n\n", count);
      exit(0);
    break;

    default: //parent
      wait(0);
      printf("Process PARENT: PID= %d, Value= %d\n", getpid(), process);
      printf("Counter value: %d\n\n", count);
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this answer is totally wrong, first of all, you have to add `#include <unistd.h>` as included library, then count is global but two different processes have their own memory, so it means when you run this, child counter will be 2 but parent count will be 0, this is not expected